# dataTable does not show newly added item after save

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable

I have a simple form using primefaces and JSF. On clicking save, it displays another jsf page where I have a primefaces datatable. It should display the newly created record in the datatable which is not the case. In order to see the new record, I have to go back to another page, then reopen the page where I have the datatable. And I can see the new record. How to solve this issue such that on clicking save I can see the new record?

```
    <p:dataTable id="dta" value="#{CarComponent.listCars}"  var="current" rows="15" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom">
    </dataTable>


     //method where listCars is populated
     public String carLists(){
        listCars = new arrayList(carDao.findAll());
        return "/jsf/listOfcars.xhtml";
     }

     //save method - on clicking save it should display the datatable

      public String save(Cars car){
        carService.save(car);
       return  "/jsf/listOfcars.xhtml";
       }


      public String getlistCars() {
          return listCars;
       }

      public void setlistCars(String listCars) {
          this.listCars = listCars;
      }
```

Comment: are you sure that you have added the car to the carList before/after saving?

Comment: Please - as best practice - do provide the versions of the relevant libraries, in this case e.g. JSF and PrimeFaces.

Comment: primefaces 5.0 and jsf 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess, but I assume that the `CarService` class is at least `ViewScoped` or even `SessionScoped`? In either way, as Fritz said in the comment, the list of cars is obviously not updated since the view is not re-rendered.

You can either do a redirect with `return "/jsf/listOfCars.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"` if the bean is `@ViewScoped`, or you have to add the newly generated car to the list of cars like

```
public String saveCar(Car car) {
    carService.save(car);
    listCars.add(car);
    return "/jsf/listOfCars.xhtml";
}
```

Comment: the bean is : @Scope("session")
@Component("CarComponent")

Comment: Well, have you tried adding the new/saved car to the bean's backing list then?

Comment: I try it and it works. But is it a good solution or simply a work around? How about performance?
I find another workaround: In the getter method of the listCars, I add this line :  listCars = new arrayList(carDao.findAll()); and it do the job. But i realise that each time the datatable will need to do a call in DB which not good performance. Am i right?

Comment: That is at least not bad practice, adding it to the frontend view model after saving it.Your idea is _bad_ for the reason mentioned: performance. You have to do a little bit of consistency-keeping between your two models, the backend and the frontend one, yourself, but that should stay handleable.